# React - Drag and drop rows and columns in table

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

Like the title says, I need to be able to select either a row or a column of a table and drag the whole row or column and drop it in another position. I can drag one or the other but not both.

An example could be a table with categories in the Y-axis and dates in the X-axis. I would need to select a whole category row and drag along the axis, same with date columns but in the other axis.

Thanks!